# Creating non-interfering window in flex

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flex4

We are building a project in Flash Builder 4(flex) and to optimize on screen space, looking to move some display content to a separate window, while the animation runs

We cannot use a pop-up as it takes control and will not allow anything else to be viewed till it is closed. Any way we can create a"read only" window that can be moved around but does not prevent the base animation from running...Thanks for any pointers

I know the title is lame- couldn't think of a better description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to use a pop-up. When you pop up the window, just set the modal property to false. That way you can still interact with the rest of your application.

**Example:**

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopUpWindow, DisplayObject(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication), false);
```